# wxPython panel not filling parent

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I have a wxPython frame containing a single custom panel. I'd like this panel to fill its frame.

```
class MyCustomFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.mainPanel = MyCustomPanel(self)
        self.SetAutoLayout(True)
```

Yet for some reason, the custom panel claims its size is always 20x20, no matter how I resize the main window.

```
class MyCustomPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print('Panel size:', self.GetSize())
```

> Panel size: (20, 20)

What's going wrong?

EDIT: From [here](https://wiki.wxpython.org/UsingSizers):

> If a wxFrame (or derived class) is to have only one child, then you don't need a sizer at all, as the default behaviour of the frame's EVT_SIZE handler (assuming there is only one child) is to resize that child to occupy all of the frame's client area.

But that's not what's happening.

Comment: It's been a long while since I messed with `wx`, but IIRC you have to include sizers for this to work properly.

Comment: @g.d.d.c That's what I had thought too, but the wiki says otherwise. I feel like I'm making some simple mistake.

Comment: You might have to wait until some initialization has occurred before the panel will be resized to the frame. Checking it at creation time might be too early.

Comment: @MarkRansom Good thought! I let the window open and resized it manually, but the size of the panel (checked on EVT_SIZE) didn't change.